# FusionCharts multi-series line chart in php

Tags: php, fusioncharts

I am looking for an example of a FusionCharts multi-series line chart created using the PHPClass API.

I can't find an example anywhere in FusionCharts online documentation.  The closest they have is a multi-series chart using MSColumn3D, but I am struggling to convert this into a line chart.

The line chart I want to make should look something like [this](http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/Contents/ChartSS/Images/MS_Line.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was using a chart of type "Line" instead of "MSLine", where "MS" stands for multi-series.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `rotateNames='1'`. That should work